# Как изменить значение CheckBox которое будет отправляться в БД

Tags: yii2

Как сделать так чтобы значение checkbox на странице отображалось так: 
[image: screen]

А в бд передавался id этого значения 
Пыталась сделать так

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'time_rec')->checkboxList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Worktime::find()->all(),'id','time_work')) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Задайте значение для label

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'time_rec')->checkboxList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Worktime::find()->all(),'id','time_work'))->label('отображаемое_значение') ?>
```